# Profiling neo4j server cypher commands

Tags: profiling, neo4j, cypher

How can I view a log of all cypher commands ran on the neo4j server ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That would be a cool feature, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all the queries ran on the `Shell`, you may look @ `\bin`, there's a file called `.shell_history`, you will find a list of all these queries..